# How to rank a record with same weight in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

Suppose I have a data say:

```
  Name   | Marks   
StudentA | 90
StudentB | 85
StudentC | 85
StudentD | 70
```

now StudentA will get 1st Rank, StudentB and StudentC will get 2nd Rank and Student D will get 4th Rank.

I know the basic rank computation if there are no duplicate weights, but how to handle if we encounter 2 similar weights as in this case there are two 85 marks which will share rank 2.

Comment: What is your current result? What are you doing to get it? What is your desired result?

Comment: I am using a variable and then every time I increment by 1, but there are two 85 in the data which share the same rank so how to handle that?

Comment: what you really want?

Comment: I want that the rank should be shared if there are equal weights, like here in case of 85, studentB and studentC will share the same rank i.e. 2

Comment: Show us your current code...

Comment: Should StudentD have a rank of 3 or 4?

Comment: `SELECT name, marks, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM student s, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY marks desc;`

Comment: @PatrickQ, It should be 4th rank, I wrote wrong initially, but than I edited.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8913662) seems to do what you want. You could just remove the unneeded columns.

Comment: Yes @PatrickQ, it seems this is what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Giorgos's fiddle...

```
SELECT name
     , marks
     , FIND_IN_SET(marks, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(marks ORDER BY marks DESC) FROM mytable)) rank
  FROM mytable;

|     Name | Marks | rank |
|----------|-------|------|
| StudentA |    90 |    1 |
| StudentB |    85 |    2 |
| StudentC |    85 |    2 |
| StudentD |    70 |    4 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc30/6

or

```
SELECT name, marks, rank
FROM (SELECT name
     , marks
     , @prev := @curr
     , @curr := marks
     , @i:=@i+1 temp
     , @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @i) AS rank
  FROM mytable
     , ( SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0, @i:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY marks DESC,name
      ) x
      ORDER 
    BY marks DESC,name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/287e07/9

Answer (score 1):

In php you can implement it in the following way:

```
$data = [
    [95, 0], [85, 0], [85, 0], [85, 0], [70, 0], [70, 0], [50, 0]
];

$rank = 0;
$previous = null;
$skippedRank = 0;
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    if ($item[0] != $previous) {
        $rank += $skippedRank+1;
        $previous = $item[0];
        $skippedRank = 0;
    } else {
        $skippedRank++;
    }

    $item[1] = $rank;
}

print_r($data);
```

where `$item[0]` is weight and `$item[1]` is rank.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need in MySQL.

Comment: @komalsarvaiya Why did you tag the question with PHP if you weren't interested in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional variable to hold the mark of the previous record:

```sql
SELECT Name, Marks,
       @rnk := IF(@prevMark = Marks, @rnk,
                  IF(@prevMark := Marks, @rnk + 1, @rnk + 1)) AS rank                
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @prevMark := 0) AS vars
ORDER BY Marks DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc30/2)

Comment: Giorgos the studentD should hold the 4th rank and not the 3rd rank as the 2nd rank is shared by 2 people.